# Spacing not wrong when printing plot with subscript in ylabel in octave

Tags: image, octave, matlab-figure

The spacing on the y axis label get all wrong when printing with `print`

The code to reproduce the issue is:

```
data1 = [1:10:100]
data2 = [100:10:200]
file = "plottest.png"

[at ho ht] = plotyy(data1,data1,data2,data2);
ylabel(at(1),"Concentration of O_2 (mol/m^3)");

print(gcf,file);
```

I'm using the qt graphics tool.

Output to figure window (and also desired result):

[image: Output to figure window (and also desired result)]

What gets printed to PNG file:

[image: What gets printed to png file]

Comment: welcome to the site! Please post a snip of runnable code so that people trying to help you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I seem to get the right result with something like `saveas(gcf, 'file.pdf')`. What OS / octave version are you using?

Comment: Windows 7
Octave version 4.2.2 (I updated to see if it corrected the mistake and it didn't)

Comment: Tried `saveas` and it didn't work

Comment: Did you try a different backend? Octave can use different backends, they don't all work equally well for all purposes.

Comment: With `gnuplot` this particular issue seems to be corrected, I would really like a solution with `qt` if possible because I have other issues with`gnuplot` and everything else I plot is with `qt` (and they look really different)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be using the latex interpreter as

`ylabel(at(1),"Concentration of $O_2$ (mol/m^3)", 'Interpreter', 'latex');`